# I'm getting classcastException , can anybody solve this?

Tags: java, data-structures, set

> getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
> class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
> (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of
> loader 'bootstrap')
> at java.base/java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:133)
> at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:806)
> at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:534)
> at java.base/java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
> at assignment3treesetdemo.addEmployee(assignment3treesetdemo.java:46)
> at assignment3treesetdemo.main(assignment3treesetdemo.java:63)

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Employee implements Comparable{
    int empid;
    String name;
    float salary;
    Employee(){}
    Employee(int empid,String name,float salary){
        this.empid=empid;
        this.name=name;
        this.salary=salary;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
            Employee emp = (Employee)o;
            if(salary==emp.salary)
                return 0;
            else if(salary>emp.salary) {
                return 1; 
                }
            else{ 
                return -1; 
                }
    }
    
    
}
public class assignment3treesetdemo extends Employee {
    TreeSet<Object> ts = new TreeSet<>();
    
    assignment3treesetdemo(int empid, String name, float salary) {
        super(empid, name, salary);
    }
    
    
    public assignment3treesetdemo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    boolean addEmployee(Employee emp[]) {
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        ts.add(emp[i].empid);
        ts.add(emp[i].name);
        ts.add(emp[i].salary);}
        return true;
    }
    void displayAllEmployees() {
        Iterator itr = ts.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    assignment3treesetdemo obj = new assignment3treesetdemo();
    Employee emp[] = new Employee[3];
    emp[0]=new Employee(101,"Adithya",50);
    emp[1]=new Employee(102,"Doshk",60);
    emp[2]=new Employee(103,"Diya",90);
    obj.addEmployee(emp);
    obj.displayAllEmployees();
    
    
}
}
```

Comment: an Integer doesn't have an IS-A relationship with String. You can't cast it, you can map it

Comment: You should not have a `TreeSet<Object>` but a `TreeSet<Employee>`. Looks like you need to take this a lot slower, work through more tutorials, ... the class structure is off, the naming patterns are not followed, why are you adding the individual properties to the treeset, ....!? `ts.add(emp)` instead of the current `add` calls should fix it probably.

Comment: Dunno what are you achieving by deconstructing a POJO into a treeset, but you put everything as string in treeset like `ts.add(emp[i].empid);`. Though TreeSet<Employee> would make more sense.

Comment: Please read the [site guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions. Pay particular attention to the page on [sample code](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting an `int` (boxed to `Integer`), a `float` (boxed to `Float`) and a `String` in the same `TreeMap`. Because you didn't specify a `Comparator` when you created the `TreeMap`, the `compareTo` methods of these separate objects are called. These `compareTo` methods are allowed to (and will) throw a `ClassCastException` if the object passed to it isn't of the same type. That's what you're seeing here.

As said before, you probably just want to add the employee itself. That way, the `compareTo` method of your `Employee` class will called and not the `compareTo` method of `Integer`, `Float` or `String.